# linux replace string if other string shows up 'n' lines before

Tags: linux, sed

I have a simple problem.

In the file with the next structure.

> condition
>   line1 
>   line2 
>   line3
>   String to change depending on the condition.

This structure repeats an undefined number of times in the file. 
i have to change the 4th line depending of the value of the 1st line.
In all the ocurrences of the file.
I've create the next function in shell script, and works fine.

```
function normalizer() {
list=$(grep -n "STRING" $1 |cut -f1 -d:|wc -l)
coso=1
while [ $coso -le $list ];
    do
    direc=$(grep -n "STRING" $1 |cut -f1 -d:|head -$coso|tail -1)
    str=$(perl -wne "print if $. == ($direc - 6)" $1)
    if  [ "$str" == "STING 2" ]; then
            sed -i "${direc}s/STRING/DORSOC CARATR/" $1
        else if     [ "$str" == "STRING 3" ]; then
                sed -i "${direc}s/STRING/DORSOC CARATU/" $1
            else
                echo dont match
            fi
    fi
  let coso=$coso+1
 done
}
```

But its not efficient because sed make a copy of the file for every change.
So, how would  you do it to make it more efficient?

EDIT:
To clarify, line 4 could not come, then I have to verify that it exists and then verify 3 lines before the condition.

Comment: Have you considered switching to awk? It allows for a more »data driven« approach, in a single process and with smaller code. If sed is present on a system, it likely has awk, too

Answer (score 1):

Give this input file:

```
condition1 line1
line2
line3
String to change depending on the condition.
condition2 line1
line2
line3
String to change depending on the condition.
condition1 line1
line2
line3
String to change depending on the condition.
```

you could use this sed script `(sed -f script.sed input)`:

```
/condition1/,+3 {t; t; s/change/XXXXX/ }
/condition2/,+3 {t; t; s/change/YYYYY/ }
```

This yields the following output:

```
condition1 line1
line2
line3
String to XXXXX depending on the condition.
condition2 line1
line2
line3
String to YYYYY depending on the condition.
condition1 line1
line2
line3
String to XXXXX depending on the condition.
```

(the +3 range address is a GNU extension, so you'll have to use GNU sed)